# Redirect "non-www" URL to "www" URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, redirect

I have an MVC4 application running on HTTP and HTTPS.  Bsaically I want to ensure that all non-www requests direct to the www. version regardless of what protocol they are using.  I am struggling to define this in URL Rewrite as my web.config rules is failing to load the site when adding the below code to the `<server.webserver>` node

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect to www" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^domain.com$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" 
        url="{MapProtocol:{HTTPS}}://www.domain.com/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
  <rewriteMaps>
    <rewriteMap name="MapProtocol">
      <add key="on" value="https" />
      <add key="off" value="http" />
    </rewriteMap>
  </rewriteMaps>
</rewrite>
```

Any advice on how to create the redirect in IIS would be great

Comment: Normally this is done using DNS, just create a `CNAME` pointing from www to your domain.

Comment: @RosdiKasim: That depends on the required behaviour: if you want the address to be rewritten in the user's browser, you're not going to get that from a `CNAME`.

Answer (score 2):

When I add such a rule using IIS, this gets added to the Web.config:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="CanonicalHostNameRule">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.domain\.com$" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domain.com/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

In the pattern-part of the condition you have `^domain.com$` whereas I have `^www\.domain\.com$`